# Using EnumTypes with Fluent NHibernate and Automapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, enums, guid

I'm looking into a project using nhibernate and I have a question on how to best accomplish the following scenario, using FluentNhibernate 1.0.0.593, and NHibernate 2.1.0.4000

My tables look like this:

```
DeviationLog:  
  Id uniqueidentifier  
  DeviationType uniqueidentifier  
  IncomingMessageId uniqueidentifier  

DeviationType:  
  Id uniqueidentifier  
  DeviationTypeCategory uniqueidentifier  
  DeviationMessage nvarchar(255)  

DeviationTypeCategory:  
  Id uniqueidentifier  
  DeviationTypeCategoryName nvarchar(255)
```

I am currently making use of automapping with conventions.

When I create an instance of Deviation, I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
var deviation = new Deviation{DeviationType=DeviationEnum.NoMatchMobileNumber};
```

Now as far as I know enums only support integral types, so this won't work without an alternative approach. I was thinking of maybe using a dictionary to this, like `Dictionary<DeviationEnum,Guid>`, and I also suspect I might need to make use of `UserTypeConvention<T>` to make this work somehow.

Anyone got experiences to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've traditionally done is use a custom IUserType class that would translate between the enum in question and how it would be persisted. However, this required a custom IUserType per enum type.

Comment: Would you be able to pastebin an example, or point to some other resouces which could be helpful ?

Comment: I would look at the source code of NHibernate for the YesNoType, which has a similar function, to turn bool into "Yes" or "No" in a string field to persist it. With the number of different enums I had, I eventually created an abstract class so each enum just had a subclass that had the mappings in it.